# Throwing NoSuchElementException for ranges

Tags: groovy, iterator

Lets say I have the following ([ideone](http://ideone.com/clone/R0E43g)):

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = x.iterator();

println y.next();
println y.next();
println y.next();
println y.next();
```

This outputs:

```
1
2
3
Caught: java.util.NoSuchElementException
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java_util_Iterator$next.call(Unknown Source)
    at prog.run(prog.groovy:7)
```

As expected.

But lets change `x = [1,2,3]` to `x = 1..3`, so the code is the following ([ideone](http://ideone.com/YqY5rm)):

```
x = 1..3
y = x.iterator();

println y.next();
println y.next();
println y.next();
println y.next();
```

Now we get the output:

```
1
2
3
null
```

And no exception is thrown. Why is this the case? It's really unexpected that [1,2,3] and 1..3 behave differently when iterating through them. It seems like such behaviour doesn't comply with `iterator`'s contract.

Is there a way for me to fix this behaviour, and will such a fix break anything else?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: Let me try to be clearer:

This is the correct usage of the Iterator class:

```
x = 1..3
y = x.iterator();

while(y.hasNext()) {
    println y.next();
}
```

The `NoSuchElement` exception is an unchecked (AKA runtime) exception.  The reason it's not checked is that it's something that should be avoidable completely without relying on the exception.  This is different than, for example, `IOException`s, which are checked and far more likely to occur during normal use.

It's not explicitly stated one way or the other in the docs, but the only time I see the `next()` method throwing a `NoSuchElementException` when the Iterator is used correctly as above is if you have a **modifiable** collection in an unsynchronized, **multi-threaded** environment that has an item **removed** between the moment you call `hasNext` and access the item using `next`.

Because the `Range` class is unmodifiable, there is no chance, ever, of that situation rising.

You should not rely on *unchecked* Exceptions to determine the functionality or state of an item.

So, I don't really think the contract has been broken.  The contract for using an iterator is to use `hasNext` before `next`, and the Range class's Iterator is not required to throw an exception just because it is being used incorrectly.

Comment: Also, you don't have any real-world examples.  But, since you are in groovy, you probably should be using `for(foo in range) { println foo }` or `range.each{ foo }`.

Comment: OverZealous: There's nothing in the text you quote that states throwing an exception is optional. There's nothing that says it's mandatory either, but it's a specification, and a specification is silly if by default it's optional. I think the language of the `iterator` specification means that `hasNext() == false` IFF `next() throws NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: Could you imagine how badly Java would break if things like `FileNotFound` exceptions were optional? It would force programmers to have `null` checks everywhere and then just guess at the issue (because `null` could mean anything).

Comment: Clinton, the File class has this convenient method called exists (or isFile or isDirectory) so you can check to see if the File exists *before* you use it.  There is no need to check for null.  Again, exceptions mean something went wrong.  Also, the NoSuchElement exception is unchecked, unlike the IOExceptions.  This is specifically because you aren't supposed to be getting it.  I stand by my opinion that the contract has not been broken by Range in this case.

Comment: Clinton: I rewrote my question based on your feedback.  I think it makes more sense in this context to clarify that this is about an *unchecked* exception, rather than all exceptions.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

use :

```
While(y.hasNext()){
 println y.next();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `IntRangeIterator` returns `null` when it has gone off the end of the Range

[As you can see in the source code for it here](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/groovy/lang/IntRange.java#L42)

I guess if you feel that this is incorrect behaviour, you should ask on the mailing lists, or post a bug to the Groovy JIRA, but as it's [been that way for 6 years](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-1553) I would imagine it's going to stay that way (as it would be a breaking change)

As other people say, you should use a `for` or `each` mechanism to iterate the `Iterator`, or if that's not possible wrapping your calls to `next()` in a `hasNext()` check should catch all cases where you're off the end.